# HOW to compare two date in sqlite of format "Oct 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM"?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUfA4.png)   **  I want to make comparison between two date of "Oct 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM" this format**

Comment: Please refer http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html. They some date time functions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare two date using following code.for date format you need to use [SimpleDateFormate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
Date date1 = new Date(millis);
```

Date date2 = new Date(millis);

```
    if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0)
    {

    }
    else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0)
    {

    }
    else 
    {
        //both are equal
    }
```